# Is it possible to run catboost predict on GPU?

Tags: machine-learning, catboost

I have a use case which requires predicting on a very large dataset. Due to this, predict takes almost 10 times the time compared to training. I was wondering if i could use the GPU for prediction or is it CPU bound. I'm using a EC2 P3.16x large(8x Tesla V100, 64 VCPUs)

Comment: Now the developers seemed to implement the prediction capability on GPU, at least release notes for version 0.16 states clearly that:
"It is now possible to apply model on GPU" There is however nothing about how to use that capability, and - at least from Python libraries & API I haven't found any clue about how to enable that. There is an open issue with the same topic (https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/560), that didn't receive an update recently.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have GPU predictor yet, only learning, metric computations and predictions computation on test set.

For some applications Catboost could benefit from GPU predictor (e.g. many decision trees), but we have no resources to implement in the near future.